# Ambari 2.4.1.0 Build Failure

Tags: python, maven, ambari

When I trying to build ambari version 2.4.1.0 in ubuntu 14.04, but it failed while building ambari metrics grafana below is the error am getting, Please suggest if I done something wrong the commend used to build the metrics is

```
 mvn -B clean install package jdeb:jdeb -DnewVersion=2.4.1.0.0 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6"


[INFO] --- jdeb:1.0.1:jdeb (default-cli) @ ambari-metrics-grafana ---
[WARNING] Creating empty debian package.
[ERROR] Failed to create debian package /home/hdfs/ambari/ambari/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-grafana/target/ambari-metrics-grafana_2.1.0.0.0_all.deb
org.vafer.jdeb.PackagingException: "/home/hdfs/ambari/ambari/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-grafana/src/main/package/deb/control" is not a valid 'control' directory)
        at org.vafer.jdeb.maven.DebMaker.makeDeb(DebMaker.java:186)
        at org.vafer.jdeb.maven.DebMojo.execute(DebMojo.java:409)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 13):

in the pom.xml file - [ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-grafana/]. Please add the following:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!--Stub execution on direct plugin call - workaround for ambari deb build process-->
            <id>stub-execution</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jdeb</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
          <attach>false</attach>
          <submodules>false</submodules>
          <controlDir>${project.basedir}/../src/main/package/deb/control</controlDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

This may resolve the above problem

Comment: worked like a charm for compiling ambari 2.6.1! Thanks!